# Upload dataframe, show content and allow editing in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am coding a dataframe viewer and in the main page there is a upload input, that reads a file and store the content in a `dcc.Store(id="store")`.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("store", "data"),
    Input("upload-data", "contents"),
    Input("upload-data", "filename"),
   )
def read_df(contents, filename):
    if contents:  # Only if there is any file updated
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        return df.to_dict('records')
```

Then the dataframe content is showed in a `dash_table.DataTable`. I would like that the stored data were updated, if you edit the table. Would be possible do that avoiding circular dependencies, duplicated outputs or non existing objects error?

```
@app.callback(
    Output("table_frame", "children"),
    [Input("store", "data"),
    Input("upload-data", "filename")]
)
def update_table_frame(df, filename):

    table = html.Div()

    if df is not None and len(df) > 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(df)

        table = html.Div(
            [
                html.H5(filename),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id="table",
                    data=df.to_dict('records'),
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, 'deletable': True,
                              'renamable': True} for i in df.columns],
                    page_current=0,
                    page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
                    page_action='custom',
                    page_count=np.ceil(len(df) / PAGE_SIZE),

                    sort_action='custom',
                    sort_mode='multi',
                    sort_by=[],

                    filter_action='custom',
                    filter_query='',

                    # row_deletable=True,
                    editable=True,

                    style_table={'overflowX': 'auto'}
                ),
                html.Button('Descargar dataframe', id='download', n_clicks=0, className="btn btn-primary"),
                dcc.Download(id="download-df")
            ]
        )

    return table
```

I tried to update data stored in the same callback that reads dataframe. However it throws all kinds of errors.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("store", "data"),
    Input("upload-data", "contents"),
    Input("upload-data", "filename"),
    Input("store", "data"),
    Input('table', "data"),
    Input('table', "columns"),
    Input('table', "page_current"),
    Input('table', "page_size")
   )
def read_df(contents, filename, df, rows, columns, page_current, page_size):

    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        input_id = ''
    else:
        input_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if input_id == 'table':
        df = pd.DataFrame(df)

        if len(rows) <= page_size:
            step = abs(page_current - previous_page)
            if previous_page < page_current:
                return pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[0:((page_current - step) * page_size)], pd.DataFrame(rows),
                                               df[((page_current - step + 1) * page_size):len(df)]], axis=0),
                                    columns=[c['name'] for c in columns]).to_dict('records')
            else:
                return pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[0:((page_current + step) * page_size)], pd.DataFrame(rows),
                                               df[((page_current + step + 1) * page_size):len(df)]], axis=0),
                                    columns=[c['name'] for c in columns]).to_dict('records')

    elif input_id == 'upload-data':
        if contents:  # Only if there is any file updated
            df = parse_data(contents, filename)
            return df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: I would use two stores: an *upload-store* which is output by an upload callback and a *data-store* which is output by a callback that takes in the table data. A third callback can generate the table by taking in the *upload-store*. And, your download callback can take in the *data-store*.  I would also move your H5 and download button into static layout with only the actual table being dynamically generated. This will avoid the download callback not finding the button input.

Comment: Thanks. That was something that I had to do. However circular dependency persist, because table data is shown in pages, so when pages are turned, it is necessary load data_store. And when table is editable it has to overwrite data_store. In short, an evident circular dependency.